# When is useCallback called when involving redux state and empty dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently running react and redux. In the simple code below, I have `[]` as dependency,

Does it mean useCallback only called once when the page loaded?
or when `state.test['data']` the redux state gets updated, useCallback will be called?

```
const mapState = useCallback(state => {
    return {
      data: state.test['data'],
    };
  }, []);

  const {
    data
  } = useMappedState(mapState);
```

**Follow up question 1**

If I want to listen to `state.test['data']`'s change, how do I do it? `[state.test['data']]` this will complain that `state` is not defined.

**Follow up question 2**

What about I need to listen to multiple states change?

```
const mapState = useCallback(state => {
    return {
      data1: state.test['data1'],
      data2: state.test['data2'],
      dataN: state.test['dataN'],
    };
  }, []);

  const {
    data
  } = useMappedState(mapState);
```

How do I make sure `data1, data2, dataN` update to date?

Comment: are you sure you can write useCallback like this.  I think you gotta use selectors if you wanna memoize the state

Comment: @Yilmaz You are correct, using useCallback in this way is pointless. UseMemo and useCallback can be used when you need to [memoize a parameterized selector](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#parameterized-and-memoized). For example `const selectUser = useMemo(()=>createSelectUser(id),[id])`

Comment: @HMR I added a follow up question. If I want to listent to state.test['data'], how do I do

Comment: @kenpeter With react-redux useSelector your component will re render when an action causes any state change and what the selector returns is different than the last time. I assume that useMappedState works the same. If it doesn't then you should make sure you're not mutating the state in your reducer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [`docs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

> `useCallback`  return  memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```

So, whenever there is changes in either of dependant value `a or b`,`useCallback` called again.

**Does it mean useCallback only called once when the page loaded?**

Its not guaranteed.Its totally depend on dependancy passed in array.If its value changes then `useCallback` is called.

EDIT:

**your use case don't need useCallback.`useSelector` should be used for this use case.**

```
const mapState = useSelector(function (state) {
    return {
        data: state.test['data']
    };
});

const {
    data
  } = useMappedState(mapState);
```

Comment: I added a follow up question. If I want to listen to state.test['data'], how do I do?

Comment: @kenpeter Updated  answer.Check EDIT

Answer (score 0):

This means `mapState` function will not be re-created in any of the subsequent renders. As it doesn't have any dependency so it will be only be created once.

eg

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
//Returns a memoized callback.
```

Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the **callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed**. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. **shouldComponentUpdate**).

Comment: I added a follow up question. If I want to listen to state.test['data'], how do I do?